# Order by in aggregation ES laravel

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

I'm trying to order elements by field descending in Elasticquent, but don't know how. This is my code:

```
    $laws_y = Law::searchByQuery([
    ],
        [
            "group_by_law_year" => ["terms" => ['field' => "law_year", "size" => 100]]
        ]);
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using the [`order` setting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order) and order by `_term: desc`:

```
$laws_y = Law::searchByQuery([
],
[
    "group_by_law_year" => [
         "terms" => [
              'field' => "law_year", 
              "order" => ["_term" => "desc" ],      <--- add this line
              "size" => 100
         ]
    ]
]);
```